# How to parse malformed HTML with Ruby and Mechanize

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I am using Mechanize to navigate a site which has badly-malformed HTML. In particular, I have a page which has checkboxes outside of a form which the server handles the requests sanely.

I would like to check these boxes and click a "Submit" button which is also outside the form, however, I can't use `Form.checkbox_with` because I don't have a `Form` object, I only have the `Page`. I can locate the checkbox on the page with

```
page.search("//input[@name='silly-checkbox']")
```

but I can't check it afterwards because Nokogiri is only used for scraping and does not track state. Is that incorrect?

How can I get a `Mechanize::Form::Checkbox` object when my checkbox is not in a form?

Answer (score 1):

You could manually load the remote page using Nokogiri, then fix the markup by finding the checkboxes outside the form and wrap them, and construct Mechanize classes by yourself from the fixed HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your form by deleting and merging new fields.

```
form.add_field!('gender', 'male')
```

[rdoc here](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/Mechanize/Form.html#M000115)